# Android Kotlin pass value from textfields to numberPicker

Tags: android, kotlin, numberpicker

So I have these values (Long and Double) in three textfields. They represent time, pace, and distance.

Now, to prevent user error I want to make them choose the values using numberPickers. I want to replace those textfields with those pickers.

This is what I have:

```
val time = timeTxtField as TextView
    val distance = distanceTxtField as TextView
    val pace = paceTxtField as TextView
    var resetRunningBtn = clearBtn
    val pickerMinutes = numberPicker as NumberPicker
    val pickerSeconds = numberPickerSeconds as NumberPicker

    pickerMinutes.minValue = 0
    pickerMinutes.maxValue = 59
    pickerMinutes.wrapSelectorWheel = false

    pickerSeconds.minValue = 0
    pickerSeconds.maxValue = 60
    pickerSeconds.wrapSelectorWheel = false




    calculateBtn.setOnClickListener {

        when {

            time.text.isEmpty() && (distance.text.isNotEmpty() && pace.text.isNotEmpty()) ->
                calculatePace(null, distance.text.toString().toDouble(), pace.text.toString())

            distance.text.isEmpty() && (time.text.isNotEmpty() && pace.text.isNotEmpty()) ->
                calculatePace(time.text.toString(), null, pace.text.toString())

            pace.text.isEmpty() && (time.text.isNotEmpty() && distance.text.isNotEmpty()) ->
                calculatePace(time.text.toString(), distance.text.toString().toDouble(), null)

            else -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please check fields",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see I have the pickers set and all that. I tried to call something like `.value` but it didn't work.

This is my [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yULyn.jpg), so you can have a bit of understanding of the concept.

Any tips? :)

Thanks

**EDIT XML:**

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.reecreate.woderator2.Controller.RunningCalculatorActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Running Pace Calculator"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/distanceTxtField"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="distance..."
    android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioType" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/timeTxtField"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="time mm:ss"
    android:inputType="time"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/distanceTxtField" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/paceTxtField"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="pace mm:ss 10:21"
    android:inputType="time"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/timeTxtField" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioType"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/milesDistanceRadioBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="140dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Miles"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/kmDistanceRadioBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView5" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/kmDistanceRadioBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="KM"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/milesRadioBtn"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.694"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</RadioGroup>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/paceRadioGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.294"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/paceTxtField">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/milesPaceRadioBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="140dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="MILES PACE"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/kmDistanceRadioBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/kmPaceRadioBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="KM PACE"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/milesDistanceRadioBtn"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.694"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</RadioGroup>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/calculateBtn"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:text="Calculate"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:hint="Result"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/paceRadioGroup" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/clearBtn"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:text="CLEAR"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/result" />
<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/numberPicker"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="119dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.407"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioType" />

<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/numberPickerSeconds"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="119dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/numberPicker" />
```

**EDIT VALUE LISTENER**

I added this, but not doing anything

```
var pickedValue: Int = pickerMinutes.value
    time.setText(Integer.toString(pickedValue))
```

................

```
 when {
        pickerMinutes.isClickable -> time.setText(Integer.toString(pickedValue))

    }

    numberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener { pickerMinutes, oldVal, newVal ->
        //store values in variable for use later
    }
```

Comment: can you post your XML file

Comment: done. under edit

Comment: Ok, Let me check

Comment: The problem is that you are not getting value from numberPickers

Comment: The Pickers are like that because I don't have more space for them. But I will end up having three. One for hours, another one for minutes and another for seconds. I will end up having 6 pickers. A set of 3 for time and another set of 3 for pace. makes sense

Comment: How can I get it @UltimateDevil ?

Comment: But in your xml there is only two numberpicker

Comment: Yes yes, I figured if I got it work with 2, it would work with 3... Or is that a misconception?

Comment: Any help will be very welcome ;D

Comment: The appropriate call for Kotlin would be `numberPicker.value`. You say it didn't work but what is this returning for you? The alternative would be to set a listener on the picker: `numberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener { picker, oldVal, newVal ->
            //store values in variable for use later
        }`

Comment: I tried something similar but didn't work. It was correct though (i knew it wasn't, but my andoird/kotlin knowledge wasn't enough.) I am reading the docs. Let me try that :)

Comment: It is picking up the default (first) number which is 0. How can I change this?

Comment: Check my edit, to see what I did

Comment: @MirandaBy have your problem is solved

Comment: No :/ can't seem to make it work with these changes...

Comment: Could you please take a look? :)

Answer (score 1):

A few general Kotlin things to note: I see you are setting variables and casting the the number pickers. You don't need to do this. In Kotlin, with the correct import, something like: `kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.my_layout_file.*`, you can simply call the xml by its id without casting, like so: `numberPicker`. That goes for your other items as well, such as the `TextView`s.

The other thing is that you shouldn't have to call `Integer.toString(pickedValue)`. You can just call `pickedValue.toString()`.

Lastly, since I am unable to see exactly how you are testing the app, my suggestion would be to do the following:

Create variables to store the picker values:

```
 var numPickerVal = 0;
 var secondsPickerVal = 0;
```

Then set a change listener for each of the pickers:

```
numberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener { picker, oldVal, newVal -> 
    numPickerVal = newVal 
}
numberPickerSeconds.setOnValueChangedListener { picker, oldVal, newVal -> 
    secondsPickerVal = newVal 
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks... on my vars it says they are never accessed? That's weird

Comment: Unfortunately, it can't all be coded for you. You will have to work out any compilation issues and continue to debug. I suggest maybe taking some more time to learn about Kotlin in general as well as it's use in Android development.